# Как закрасить QPushButton наполовину с помощью метода setStyleSheet?

Tags: python, pyqt

Необходимо сделать заливку кнопки на 50% без плавного перехода цвета (QLinearGradient) с помощью setStyleSheet (без переопределения метода paint в наследующемся от QPushButton классе)(если это возможно). Нужна чёткая граница. Например: левая половина синий, правая половина белый, без плавного перехода синего цвета в белый. Пробовал сделать как в примере ниже, но это с плавным переходом синего в белый.

```
        self.push_button_left_fill.setStyleSheet(f'''
        border: 2px solid black;
        Border-radius: 10px;
        Background-color:
        QLinearGradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
        stop: 0 #0000ff,
        stop: 0.4 #0000ff,
        stop: 1 white);''')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использовал QtDisigner, в нем у меня получился вот такой вариант:

`background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.500, y1:0, x2:0.501, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: А можете подсказать что такое spread:pad? В руководстве по таблицам стилей Qt не нашёл. Где подобные опции можно найти? Хотя, удалил эту часть, вроде не на что не влияет.